# oracle: how to access dba_audit_object from another schema

Tags: oracle

I need to extract information from the table dba_audit_object within a package which I'm defining in a different schema. The purpose is to eventually display the extracted data in an Oracle form.

If I do `SELECT * FROM dba_audit_object` in SQL Developer I get the results.

However if I write the same SELECT in a package it says: `ORA-00942 table or view does not exist`. I get the same error also if I try to create a view within my schema based on the same SELECT statement.

I've tried using `sys.dba_audit_object` but this still gives me same error message.

Does anyone know how I should/can proceed please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. You should log in as SYS and do the following:

GRANT SELECT ON DBA_AUDIT_OBJECT TO PUBLIC;

Only then will other schemas be able to use it to create a new view or within a package.

Comment: ok thanks then! i did read it several times but couldn't work out the second part of your sentence. thx to jonearles too! that's exactly the part which i didn't understand at first. all's well now :)

Answer (score 1):

Provide grants like

```
GRANT SELECT ON DBA_AUDIT_OBJECT TO THE_SCHEMA_FROM_WHERE_YOU_NEED_ACCESS;
```

If you already have a synonym then you cannot provide grants for a synonym. In that case, use

```
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.DBA_AUDIT_OBJECT TO THE_SCHEMA_FROM_WHERE_YOU_NEED_ACCESS;
```

and **run it as SYS**.

Comment: hi
why can't i grant select on a public synonym? 
there was already a PUBLIC synonym DBA_AUDIT_OBJECT defined in schema SYS and my DBA granted select to my ROLE. yet it still doesn't work.
why not?

Comment: @user3322952 You need to grant it *directly* to the owner of the package, not just to a role assigned to the owner of the package.